# Getting Null Values while traversing a List with non null values in Multithreaded Environment

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

In the below snippet, I am iterating over a list using a `for-each loop`, and encountering `null` values on Performance Testing Servers with thousand of threads and logged in users.

```
List<Attribute> attributes = getRoleListAttributes();
Map<String, String> rolesAttribute = new HashMap<String, String>();

//Doing Null Check to be on safer side
if( attributes != null && !attributes.isEmpty() ) 
{
  for( Attribute attr : attributes )<------ Here getting attr as null
  {
    if( attr != null && attr.getApiAlias() != null && attr.getInternalName() != null  )
    {
      rolesAttribute.put( attr.getApiAlias(), attr.getInternalName() );
    }
    else
    { // In Server logs i am getting this error.
      LOGGER.error("Invalid Role Attribute (%s)",attr);
    }
  }
}
```

This behavior is definitely possible when `List<Attribute> attributes` actually contains null but I also have Null check in `getRoleListAttributes();`

**Implementation of getRoleListAttributes method:**

```
public List<Attribute> getRoleListAttributes()
  {
    if( _apiEnabled == null )
    {
      if( _attributes != null && !_attributes.isEmpty() )
      {
        _validRoles = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        for( String attrInternalName : _attributes.keySet() )
        {
          Attribute attr = _attributes.get( attrInternalName );
          if( attr != null )
          {
            if( attr.getApiAlias() != null && attr.getApiAlias().trim().length() > 0 )
            {
              _validRoles.add( attr );
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return _apiEnabled;
  }
```

I have null check everywhere there is no place a null can enter in **rolesAttribute** `List`.

The only doubt I have is while traversing List in the first method is there a possibility that `one thread` is inside getRoleListAttributes()method and `_validRoles` ArrayList starts resizing itself from it's initial capacity and at the very same moment `thread-1` in the first method receives null value.

**In general what will happen if `get(object)` is called on ArrayList while the list is trying to resizing itself. ?**

Comment: Why are you returning `_apiEnabled` from `getRoleListAttributes()`?  It looks like you might want to return `_validRoles`

Comment: Have you tried to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?  This option is a thread-safe variant of ArrayList.

Comment: Plus I would have expected something like [Collections.synchronizedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-)

Comment: @Guys thanks for your suggestions, I understand i have thread safe options, i am not searching the solutions to fix this, more interested in why this issue is happening.

Comment: @JoopEggen, Yes I know that there are many options to avoid this scenario, but i want to know the Root cause. more important the last question's answer